# Stability analysis of equilibrium point of non-linear ODE system with Jacobian going to infinity

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, stability

Let's say I have a nonlinear system of ODEs, where one of equations looks like:

$$
\frac{dX_i}{dt} = a_1X_0+\dotsb+a_j\frac{X_j^{0.5}}{X_j^{0.5}+b_j^{0.5}}+\dotsb.
$$

And equilibrium point is **0**. I want to investigate the stability of a given point depending on the initial conditions ($X_k(0) \ge 0$, $k=0,\dotsc,n$). The usual procedure: linearization of the system does not work, since the Jacobian will tend to infinity for a term with power of 0.5.

> Is there any way to get around this problem?
>
> Is there any adequate numerical algorithm for investigating the stability of a point (if system contains, for example, up to 10 equations)?

For instance, let's take the model from "*[Mathematical modeling and stability analysis of macrophage activation in left ventricular
remodeling post-myocardial infarction](https://doi.org/10.1186/1471-2164-13-s6-s21)*" by Yunji Wang et al.

[image: Excerpt from paper]

And here instead of $\frac{T_\alpha}{T_\alpha +c_{T_\alpha}}$ we'll use $\frac{T_\alpha^{0.5}}{T_\alpha^{0.5} +c_{T_\alpha}^{0.5}}$.

There will be one (not only) stationary point at $\mathbf0$. I want to investigate stability of this particular point.

Comment: Can you design a simple model that reflects the main features of your system? The most interesting part is the equation for $\dot X_j$: there should be something that prevents it from hitting $0$ and I want to see what that is before saying anything.

Comment: Let's imagine a simple chemical (or biological) system in which there are catalysts and inhibitors. It is constructed in such a way that $X_i$ never becomes negative, since obviously we are dealing with concentrations and densities. So, $X(t)_j^{0.5}+b_j^{0.5} > 0$ for all t. @fedja

Comment: Sorry for my being unclear: I meant a minimal example of an actual system of ODE's that has all those features (I suspect that in addition to having an unbounded Jacobian, your system is also degenerate at the origin in a certain way (like those chemical system where the RHS is the sum of products of variables) at least as long as $X_j$ is concerned. And if the RHS are always all positive, what stability at $0$ can we be talking about?

Comment: I've added an example into my question :) What type of degeneracy we are talking about here? @fedja

Comment: I see. That clarifies a lot about the system structure. Let me think of it now. By degeneracy I meant something like that in the system $\dot C=-AC, \dot A=-A$ when there is no or degenerate linear part at $(0,0)$, so the Jacobian test becomes inconclusive.

Comment: Doesn't this imply the function is not Lipschitz and hence even uniqueness is not guaranteed ?

Comment: @PiyushGrover You are not allowed to start at $0$ in such models. The question is about the solutions remaining in the "positive octant"  for all times where everything is OK. But this requires quite special structure of the system (see my model description below).

Comment: I guess I figured it out by now and it is exactly as I supposed. It is too late to post today and I'll be pretty busy tomorrow, but I'll try to make an update soon. Note also that when you suggested to replace $T_a/(T_a+c_{T_a})$ by the square root expression in the posted model, you didn't notice that that ratio appears only in the product with another variable ($M_{un}$ in that case). If that variable is a part of your equilibrium at $0$ (so you have $X_k\sqrt{X_j}$, not $\sqrt{X_j}$ alone), then it can be disregarded as a "higher order term" and the usual linear stability analysis applies.

Answer (score 3):

This is what (in my opinion) the general setup is and what should happen and why. Note that I haven't proved anything yet. What I offer is just a back of envelope computation at the physicist level of rigor (which is not much from the mathematical point of view, but you can check it against numerical simulations, nevertheless, and see if it makes sense). I'll update it when I understand things better.

You have a system of the kind $\dot X=-DX+AX+e_{i_0}\psi(\sqrt{X_1})+O(\|X\|^2)$ where $\psi(x)$ is a smooth function behaving like $x$ near $0$, $e_i$ is the vector with $i_0$-th coordinate $1$ and the rest $0$ for $i_0\ne 1$, $D$ is a diagonal matrix with positive elements on the diagonal (degradation matrix in your example), $A$ is a matrix with non-negative entries that has $0$ on the diagonal, and $O(\|X\|^2)$ is some quadratic and higher order nonsense.

We say that $k$ feeds upon $\ell\ne k$ if $A_{k,\ell}>0$. We say that $i$ is at the level $m\ge 0$ in the food chain starting from $i_0$ if there is a sequence of indices $i=i_m,i_{m-1},\dots, i_0$ in which each index feeds on the next one and $m$ is the smallest length of any such sequence (which is the same as if we consider an oriented graph with the adjacency matrix induced by $A$ and measure the number of steps needed to reach $i$ from $i_0$).

Case 1. $1$ is at some finite level $m$. Then what should happen is the following. We have a solution $X=X(t)$ in which
$X_1$ is of order $t^{2p-2}$, if $i$ is at level $\ell$, then $X_i$ is of order $t^{p+\ell}$, and to have it consistent with the statement about $X_1$ (to close the loop), we must have $2p-2=p+m$, so $p=m+2$. That solution can start at arbitrarily small $t$ and grow to fixed size at $t=1$, so the system is always unstable in this case.

Case 2: $1$ is not in the above food chain. Then, if we run the food chain from $1$ in the other direction (indices $1$ feeds on, indices indices $1$ feeds on feed on, etc.), we'll get some set if indices $I$ containing $1$ but not $I_0$ that feed only on each other. Then one needs to investigate the linear stability of the corresponding submatrix. If it is stable, one should investigate the linear stability of the submatrix corresponding to the complementary set $I^c$ of indices. If that one is stable too, the whole system is stable.

As I said, I have no proofs yet, just an educated guess. The person who voted to close the question has, apparently, been able to figure everything out in under 5 minutes and could explain the full solution in under 10, but he/she decided not to condescend to poor idiots like myself and left no remark, so we'll have to investigate this problem using our inferior brains. :-)